# Add variable to attribute

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I need to attribute `action` url to be composed of "url" + variable.
Like this:

```html
    <script>
    var domain = "@example.com";
    </script>
    <body>
    <form action=("https://login.example.com/&" + domain) id="login_form" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Log in</button>
    </form>
```

I need to make label with lastname and send the label as lastname@example.com by this form.

Comment: Can you please explain your question a little more

Comment: `I need to make label with lastname and send the label as lastname@example.com by this form.` <-- This doesn't seem to be related to anything you've shown in your code. Also, what do you mean by "send a label"?

Comment: @ScottMarcus input label of the form

Comment: I'm sorry, but please explain what you mean by `input label of the form` as there is no such thing.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<script>
    var domain = "@camosoft.cz";
    var url = "https://login.szn.cz//?returnURL=https://email.seznam.cz/&serviceId=email&" + domain
    document.getElementsById("login_form").setAttribute("action", url);
</script>
<body>
<form action="" id="login_form" method="get">
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the form element using `document.querySelector`. Using `setAttribute` add the variable to the action attribute and give it to the form

```js
    var domain = "@camosoft.cz";
    var a=document.querySelector('form').getAttribute('action');
    document.querySelector('form').setAttribute('action',a+domain);
```

```html
    <body>
    <form action="https://login.szn.cz//?returnURL=https://email.seznam.cz/&serviceId=email&" + domain id="login_form" method="get">d</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form action dynamically with the help of Javascript after page load.

Example:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('login_form');
var domain = "@camosoft.cz";
var action = "https://login.szn.cz//?returnURL=https://email.seznam.cz/&serviceId=email&" + domain
if(frm) {
   frm.action = action;
}
```

Comment: Adding ` || null` doesn't really provide any value. If the element isn't found, `frm` will be `undefined`, which still works with `if(frm)`. But frankly, testing for the existence of one of your own elements is rarely needed in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate the string and then set the final value via JavaScript, not inline in HTML.

Also, place your `script` element just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`) so that by the time the parser reaches it, all the HTML will have been parsed into memory.

Lastly, the parenthesis in your HTML around your attribute value is incorrect.

```html
<body>
  <form action="https://login.szn.cz//?returnURL=https://email.seznam.cz/&serviceId=email&" id="login_form" method="get">
    
  </form>
  <script>
    var domain = "@camosoft.cz";

    // concatenate the domain on to the end of the current action:
    document.querySelector("form").action += domain;

    console.log(document.querySelector("form").action);  // <-- Verify results
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Log printing correct. But probably rewritting by `<input type="text" name="username">` in url. Without @camosoft.cz